# Advice on the best way to collect values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I need to save all the color values ​​of the elements in the pages of my site and put them in a database. I thought I'd do it this way:

First thing I'm going to pick up the rgb values ​​of each element so

```
$("*").each(function(e){
  createColorArray($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
});
```

then in the function createColorArray store into an array all the values ​​that are passed

```
function createColorArray(rgbColor)
{
  //Create rgb array
}
```

and finally remove duplicate items from my array

```
function removeDoupe(ar) {
var temp = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
    temp[ar[i]] = true;
var r = [];
for (var k in temp)
    r.push(k);
return r;
}
```

now my question is, 
how recommended to create the array? directly inside the $ ("*") or in a dedicated function as I'm thinking? also i need than once removed duplicates in the new array "clean" as well as the rgb value I would have also given the number of times that value was in the original. 
Some example code?

Comment: Why add duplicates in the first place?

Comment: You should probably do the checking for duplicates *before* the value is added to the array in the first place.

Comment: A little but it seems to me that improve performance in terms of speed using the control of duplicate values outside the $ (*)

Comment: Use an attribute selector -

var colorArray= $('[background-color]').attr("background-color");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, why not check for duplicates earlier? A simple example:

```
var colors = [];

$('*').each(function(i, el){    

    var $element = $(el),
        color = $element.css('background-color');

    if(!~$.inArray(color, colors))
        colors.push(color);
});

console.log(colors);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sL9oeywk/

Comment: I would also do $('body').find('*'), so as to ignore elements in the <head>.

Comment: @LShetty Yes, I intentionally left some tuning work for OP ;)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to do it all while you are working on it. Heres a way you could potentially do it:

```
var colors = new Array();
var tempColors = {};

$(".colors").each(function(){
    var c = $(this).val();
    // check if the color exists without looping
    if(typeof tempColors[c] == "undefined"){
        // if it doesn't, add it to both variables.
        tempColors[c] = true;
        colors.push(c);
    }
});
```

This will result in two variables: one is an object that you don't have to loop through to find out if you defined it before, one is a colors array that you push to using standard javascript.

You shouldn't make it a dedicated function if you are not reusing it, but you could make it an object like this:

```
var colors = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.array = new Array();
    // this is a dedicated check function so we don't need separate variables.
    // returns true if the color exists, false otherwise
    self.check = function(color){
        for(var i =0; i < self.array.length; i++){
            if(self.array[i] === color) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    self.add = function(color){
        // use the check function, if it returns false, the color does not exist yet.
        if(!self.check(color)){
            self.array.push(c);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then instantiate a colorlist using `var colorlist = new colors();` and add colors using `colorlist.add("dd0300")`. Accessing the array can be done by requesting `colorlist.array`.